# Mysql find root parent of shared post

Tags: mysql, sharing

I have to manage sharing-post like on Facebook here is how I intend to do it.

I have a table which contains articles with a parent_id field and I would like to change state of all shared articles to 0 when parent is deleted(when parent state = 0)

```
articles

+----+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
| id | content   | user_id | parent_id  | state  |
+----+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
| 1  | content   | 2       | null       |   1    | 
| 2  | content   | 5       | null       |   1    |
| 3  | content   | 4       | 2          |   1    |
| 4  | content   | 6       | null       |   1    |
| 5  | content   | 7       | 1          |   1    |
| 6  | content   | 1       | 3          |   1    |
| ...| ...       | ...     | ...        |   ...  |
+----------------+---------+------------+--------+
```

Example according to the articles table above:

User 4 shares article 2 and user 1 shares article 3 which is a child of the article 2. So when article 2(root article) is deleted(his state change to 0) all child articles(3 & 6) state have to also change to 0.

How to accomplish this ?

Any other way to manage sharing post will be great appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you can program a trigger on delete:

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

There's an example:

BEFORE INSERT ON `articles`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE articles SET parent_id = 0 WHERE parent.id = OLD.parent_id;
END

If you need the trigger on multiple tables, you can program a stored procedure and call it on the trigger instead of programming the query on every table.

Also, if you want to avoid having lost / unlinked records, you can have a foreign key if you use INNODB tables. With a foreign key, you cannot insert a parent_id who not exists, or you cannot delete a register if they have any childs.

You can check documentation about foreign keys here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html